# What command does "Sync Branch" do on Github application

Tags: macos, git, github

As the title suggests, which operations does the "sync branch" perform on the github application for OS X? Does it do a full clone of the repo again?

Comment: I would assume it pulls the latest commits from the remote.

Answer (score 7):

According to this [**article**](https://help.github.com/articles/how-can-i-push-or-pull) on GitHub app documentation:

No, **SyncBranch** doesn't perform a full clone of the repo. It just **pull the changes in origin** and **push all the commits** you haven't pushed yet, all in a **single step**.

---

See full [**article**](https://help.github.com/articles/how-can-i-push-or-pull) content:

> ## How can I push or pull?
>
> If your repository has a remote connected, we encourage you to use the
> **Sync Branch** button. In one step, we'll bring in new changes from the
> remote and push any commits you haven't published yet. Behind the
> scenes, we do the equivalent of a git pull --rebase (but make sure to
> never rewrite merges).

[image]

> If you would like to perform a standard pull or push without syncing
> everything, you can do so via the **Repository** menu item.

[image]

Comment: Hmm. This is odd. I have 2 branches; master and dev. My remote repo always sits on the master brach. I develop locally on the dev brach. When I commit changes, I use the "commit and sync" button. This pushes my changes to my remote repo. I then go onto my remote machine and run "git merge dev master". This moves all my changes from dev to master. If on my local machine I run "git pull --rebase", it doesn't seem to do the same as the "sync branch" button. The main difference is that the master branch doesn't get updated (it says "merge dev master" on the master branch when I use sync branch).

Comment: It seems that the sync branch button actually loops through the branches and performs a `git pull` on each one.

Comment: @dotty, yes, it probably does that, since it says it **brings in new changes from the remote**, and I understand it means ALL new changes, and that would mean all the changes in all the branches...